# How to share a object with node + express

Tags: node.js, express, module

I´m using Node + express and I´m trying to figure out how to share objects instances in the main js file with my modules. I have this code at bellow.

```
var express = require('express');

//libs
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var conf      = require('config');
var logConf   = conf.get('log');
var winston = require('winston');


//modules
var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var camera = require('./routes/camera');
var face = require('./routes/face');
var secret = require('./routes/secret');
var attendance = require('./routes/attendance');
var azure = require('./routes/azure-test');

//configuring log
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
      new (winston.transports.Console)(),
      new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: logConf.get('file') })
    ]
  });

require('events').EventEmitter.prototype._maxListeners = 200;

var app = express();

/*Handling CORS*/
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE');
  next();
});

/*trying to avoid undesirable response code. 
 *Ex: you send 200 and express send 304 ... annoying!
 */
app.disable('etag');

//setting image dir for static server
app.use("/tmp", express.static(__dirname + '/tmp'));
app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
//app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

//putting modules in the game...
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/camera', camera);
app.use('/face', face);
app.use('/attendance', attendance);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);

});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  console.error("LOCALS ERRORS: " + res.locals.error);
  console.error("LOCALS MESSAGES: " + err.message);
  JSON.stringify(res.locals.error || err.message)});

});

//Set port
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 7000) ;

//setting public on static server
//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//setting server up
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});


logger.info('starting application');

module.exports = app;
```

The goal is not to configure and instance a new 'winston' object in all modules. I´m a noobie in Node and express, so if you have some documentation about it(I was not able to find out), please point to me! If you prefer to give me the answer directly, better!

Thx!

Comment: what is the problem with the current scenario? if you have a module.exports in your module then it works perfectly fine

Comment: My problem is I can´t access my 'logger' object in my modules. Obviously I don´t know what I´m doing to solve that! So, can you point me some documentation or give me an objective answer about how can I find my 'logger' object in my modules, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make 'shared' module and define there things you need to share

for example

```
// shared.js
var winston = require('winston');
var conf      = require('config');
var logConf   = conf.get('log');

var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
      new (winston.transports.Console)(),
      new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: logConf.get('file') })
    ]
  });

module.exports = {
    logger: logger
    // other things 
}
```

in other files just require shared.js and use

```
var shared = require('./shared');
var logger = shared.logger;
```

Comment: So,  logger is coming undefined :-(

Comment: I try on my local machine and it works fine only difference is { filename: 'somefile.log' }

Comment: Humm... Is not only difference! You´re not using 'express'. I don´t know if it makes any difference.

Comment: Sorry, I´m a fool! Works fine now! It´s a shame it not works sharing from main app. But is better than configure in all modules. 

Thanks!